# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error with Route53 nameservers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I setup a hosted zone in Route 53 along with an Alias A record pointing to a load balancer (using a SSL cert). When I insert the nameserver entries into my DNS, I immediately get a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN error when visiting the site - both with and without www.

It's pretty straight forward so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I know the load balancers work since the full A record URLs work fine - the problem occurs when inserting the nameserver entries.

Comment: Did you purchase a domain and point the registrar NS records to point to Route 53?

Comment: Yep I did, all 4 nameservers are the ones from the zone file in route 53